# viewpager didn't load the first page at the first time, but will load it after swipe to the last page

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and I don't have too much SO coins.
Basically, my project has a main screen activity and it contains 3 tabs, which are MyGiftsFragment, FriendsGiftsFragment and AboutMeFragment. I implemented tablayout and viewpager here. The problem is when I sign in the app, the first page(MyGiftsFragment) is empty, not loading anything(sometimes it loaded.) But when I swiped to the last tab(AboutMeFragment) and come back to the first tab, the content will be loaded. And this only works when I swiped to the last tab.

Due to my limit English, I am not sure if I explain the question clear. If you need any further information, please comment. I've searched the "setUserVisibleHint" and "setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener)", but it seems that they are not what I want. Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Here are my MainScreenActivity code.

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainScreenActivity.class.getName();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ArrayList<Gift> mGiftArray;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        /** Setup Toolbar and ActionBar. */
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /** Setup DrawerLayout. */
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        /** 1.Setup drawer header content: Title and profile picture. */
        View drawerHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        NetworkImageView drawerPicture = (NetworkImageView) drawerHeader.findViewById(R.id.drawer_picture);
        NetworkImageView coverPicture = (NetworkImageView) drawerHeader.findViewById(R.id.cover_picture);

        /** Fetch data from SharePreferences. */
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("test", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String drawerPictureUrl = mSharedPreferences.getString("picture", "");
        String coverPictureUrl = mSharedPreferences.getString("cover", "");
        ImageLoader imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(MainScreenActivity.this.getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
        drawerPicture.setImageUrl(drawerPictureUrl, imageLoader);
        coverPicture.setImageUrl(coverPictureUrl, imageLoader);


        /** 2.Setup drawer body content: Name, E-mail and birthday. */
        /** Fetch data from SharePreferences. */
        String username = mSharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
        String email = mSharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
        String birthday = mSharedPreferences.getString("birthday", "");
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem nav_name = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_item_name);
        nav_name.setTitle(username);
        MenuItem nav_email = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_item_email);
        nav_email.setTitle(email);
        MenuItem nav_birthday = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_item_birthday);
        nav_birthday.setTitle(birthday);

        /** Setup item onSelectedListener. */
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                Intent intent;

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_name) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_email) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_birthday) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_payment) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_refresh) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                    return true;
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_logout) {

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    facebookLogout();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        /** Setup FloatingActionButton. */
        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        TabPagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                animateFab(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
//
//        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//                // do your work
//            }
//        });
    }

    private void animateFab(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fab.show();
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Context context = view.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                fab.show();
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Context context = view.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddGiftsActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                break;

            default:
                fab.hide();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                facebookLogout();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    static class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public TabPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mContext = context;
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new MyGiftsFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new FriendsGiftsFragment();
            } else {
                return new AboutMeFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return mContext.getString(R.string.my_gifts);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return mContext.getString(R.string.friends_gifts);
            } else {
                return mContext.getString(R.string.about_me);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(false);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void facebookLogout() {
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Log.e("22", "Not sign out yet.");
        } else {
            Log.e("22", "Signed out already.");
        }
        mAuth.signOut();
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Log.e("22", "Not sign out yet.");
        } else {
            Log.e("22", "Signed out already.");
        }
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Log.e("facebook", "logout");
        startActivity(new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, FacebookLoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

And here is MyGiftsFragment

```
public class MyGiftsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = MyGiftsFragment.class.getName();
    private ArrayList<Gift> mGiftArray;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private String facebookId;

    public MyGiftsFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mGiftArray = new ArrayList<>();

        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("test", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebookId = mSharedPreferences.getString("facebookId", "");


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference myWishList = mDatabase.child("user/" + facebookId + "/my_gift/" + "/wish_list");
        myWishList.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            /** Add new gift */
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                mGiftArray.clear();
                /** com.jluo80.amazinggifter.MyGiftsFragment:-KMa77KnGU5hsF8dngVc*/
                final String uniqueKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + uniqueKey);
                /** com.jluo80.amazinggifter.MyGiftsFragment:true */
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getValue());

                DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("gift").child(uniqueKey);
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot item) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Single" + item.getKey());
                        System.out.println("test" + item.getValue());
                        Gift gift = item.getValue(Gift.class);
                        gift.setUnique_key(uniqueKey);
                        System.out.println(gift.getInitiator_id() + "&&&&&&&" + gift.getReceiver_id());

                        String end = gift.getDue_date();
                        String start = getCurrentDate();
                        if(gift.getProgress() <= gift.getPrice() && end.compareTo(start) >= 0) {
                            mGiftArray.add(gift);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyGiftRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), mGiftArray));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

            }
        });


        DatabaseReference fromFriendsList = mDatabase.child("user/" + facebookId + "/my_gift/" + "/from_friends");
        fromFriendsList.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            /** Add new gift */
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//                mGiftArray.clear();
                /** com.jluo80.amazinggifter.MyGiftsFragment:-KMa77KnGU5hsF8dngVc*/
                final String uniqueKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + uniqueKey);
                /** com.jluo80.amazinggifter.MyGiftsFragment:true */
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getValue());

                DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("gift/" + uniqueKey);
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot item) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Single" + item.getKey());
                        System.out.println("test" + item.getValue());
                        Gift gift = item.getValue(Gift.class);
                        gift.setUnique_key(uniqueKey);
                        System.out.println(gift.getInitiator_id() + "&&&&&&&" + gift.getReceiver_id());

                        String end = gift.getDue_date();
                        String start = getCurrentDate();
                        if(gift.getProgress() <= gift.getPrice() && end.compareTo(start) >= 0) {
                            mGiftArray.add(gift);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyGiftRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), mGiftArray));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public String getCurrentDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        return mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Post source for MyGiftsFragment, please

Comment: @PSchuette I edit the post with MyGiftsFragment. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I would suggest handling your database calls in the onCreate() lifecycle and  view stuff in onCreateView or onResume. onCreateView will only be called when the ViewPager is inflated (because view will not be destroyed until parent view is removed). onResume will be called when the view loses focus (onPause) and regains it. I would also suggest calling onDatasetChanged() for your recycler adapter (if it is a list adapter) after adding things to your db. I am not familiar with firebase, though, so this could be handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Please add this line before setting adapter. This will fix the issue

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

**Offscreen page limit** will decide how many adjacent pages need to be loaded when you see a page. So in your case set it to 3 (all pages).

Then your code will change to,

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);  //Add this
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes sir.  OffscreenPagelimit is required.

Comment: This tells the ViewPager how many fragments views to hold in memory. This is somewhat greedy if the views do not need to be maintained. I think this is a matter of using the fragment/view pager lifecycle properly