# ViewPager TabLayout issue: tab fragment content only appears after last tab has been swiped to

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a ViewPager to which I am adding 3 tab fragments dynamically:

```
 private void addTabs(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new QuotesFragment(), "Quotes");
    adapter.addFragment(new BooksFragment(), "Books");
    adapter.addFragment(new ExercisesFragment(), "Exercises");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here's the code of the fragment that is not working as expected:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.quotes_recycler);
    layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    MasonryAdapter adapter = new MasonryAdapter(context, quotesList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The RecyclerView view holders form `QuotesFragment()` will not show up at parent Activity's start. They only show up when I have scrolled to the last tab (`ExercisesFragment()` in this case) and returned to the first one. Checking in Hierarchy Viewer it seems that at the app start the RecyclerView is initialized (the container takes necessary space on the screen), but its children are not.

What's odd, when I change the order in which I am adding tabs like so (note my problematic tab is now in the middle):

```
private void addTabs(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ExercisesFragment(), "Exercises");
    adapter.addFragment(new QuotesFragment(), "Quotes");
    adapter.addFragment(new BookFragment(), "Books");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

it does never load! I have tried various things, and there's even one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471105/viewpager-didnt-load-the-first-page-at-the-first-time-but-will-load-it-after-s) about exactly the same problem, but it does not help in my case. Could it have to do with Fragment/ViewPager lifecycle or implicit methods?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your tabs are inside a fragment or an activity?

Comment: I am calling addTabs() inside an Activity. It extends my `BaseActivity` which in turn extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Any error trace? warning or something? I cant spot any mistake on your code. It shouldn't be the solution but you can try to replace getSupportFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentManager().

Comment: What exactly is ViewPagerAdapter? Some library? Your fragment never loads in the middle because its not actually reloaded (ViewPager always holds adjacent page in memory). We just need to figure out why it doesn't load the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work and it's dumb simple really. I was calling my method that loads quotes from JSON inside Fragment's `onCreate()` instead of `onViewCreated()`. When I moved it to `onViewCreated()` (after setting adapter and layout manager) it started working.

Comment: Well, that's upto you lidkxx :)